# Avoid string concatenation for parameters when they are null

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

In C# I have query like that:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = @name";
...
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

if (price.HasValue)
{
    query += " AND price = @price";
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price.Value);
}
..
```

How to avoid `if` statements?  In above example I have only one parameter but in my code I have several parameters what is mean that I have several `if` statements

Comment: Could do this with one `if` per parameter, not two.

Comment: Yes, but if I have then parameters still I need ten `ifs`

Comment: You want to build the sql query without using ANY if or you want to remove one from the provided two?

Comment: I want to replace `if` statements

Comment: I _guess_ you want this for "typing less". So the usual advice applies: put the logic in a separate method. -- probably an Extension method (or several) on `IDbCommand` -- (also, I _think_ `AddWithValue` is deprecated)

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: I only asking if it is possible :) If it's wasting of time I will not spend more time about that

Comment: Something like: `public static class DbCommandExtension { public static void AddParameterWithValue<T>(this IDbCommand command, ref string query, string columnName, string parameterName, T? value) where T : struct { if (!value.HasValue) return; query += $" AND {columnName} = @{parameterName}"; var parameter = command.CreateParameter(); parameter.ParameterName = parameterName; parameter.Value = value.GetValueOrDefault(); command.Parameters.Add(parameter); } }` maybe? And then call it: `da.SelectCommand.AddParameterWithValue(ref query, "price", "price", price)`

Comment: Thanks, somehing like that and answer from @NajiMakhoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with SQL query without any IFs , something like :

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = @name AND (@price IS NULL OR price = @price)";
```